# convert pdf files to image using imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

i have installed imageMagick and ghostscript from online and put it inside mamp but m not getting how to include them in my php code..
by googling i found a code

```
<?php
    $pdf = 'serviceReport.pdf';
    $save = 'output.jpg';

    exec('convert "'.$pdf.'" -colorspace RGB -resize 800 "'.$save.'"', $output, $return_var);

?>
```

but m not getting the result..can anyone help with this

Comment: Is the PDF multi page?  You may find the output filename postfixed by page number.  You should specify the page you want to image if not all of them with `serviceReport.pdf[0]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is much effective to use the php extension ImageMagick offers (Imagick) instead of command line tools:

```
<?php
// ...
$img = new \Imagick();
$img->readimage($filedata['tmp_name']); // this can be a pdf file!
$img->setResolution(300,300);
$img->writeImage(sprintf('%1$s/%2$s.jpg', $basepath, $basename));
// ...
?>
```

Another alternative is to use the poppler tools instead. They offer much faster processing.